# WordPress There is an error log for a transaction we did not do

Tags: errors

I'm new to wordpress and I have no code information. I encountered an error in the log file that I did not perform. Who can do how. Have I been attacked?

```
[17-Apr-2020 20:35:55 UTC] require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main, WP->query_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts tarafından oluşturulan SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%Takipte Kalırsanız Diğer Bölümleri Kaçırmassınız - - Sıfır Bir Sezon Final  https://yadi.sk/i/I-o3mPN0NVZEqw - - Sıfır Bir Sinema  https://yadi.sk/i/vsW2EEc0udQd0Q%') OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%Takipte Kalırsanız Diğer Bölümleri Kaçırmassınız - - Sıfır Bir Sezon Final  https://yadi.sk/i/I-o3mPN0NVZEqw - - Sıfır Bir Sinema  https://yadi.sk/i/vsW2EEc0udQd0Q%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%Takipte Kalırsanız Diğer Bölümleri Kaçırmassınız - - Sıfır Bir Sezon Final  https://yadi.sk/i/I-o3mPN0NVZEqw - - Sıfır Bir Sinema  https://yadi.sk/i/vsW2EEc0udQd0Q%')))  AND (wp_posts.post_password = '')  AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment') AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY (CASE WHEN wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%Takipte Kalırsanız Diğer Bölümleri Kaçırmassınız - - Sıfır Bir Sezon Final  https://yadi.sk/i/I-o3mPN0NVZEqw - - Sıfır Bir Sinema  https://yadi.sk/i/vsW2EEc0udQd0Q%' THEN 2 ELSE 6 END), wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10 sorgusu için WordPress veritabanı hatası Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'
```

Comment: The error is resulting from the SQL trying to query two different collations.  You can read more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/troubleshooting-illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql

So, and I'm not sure why, it appears that two records in the DB were stored with different collations - has anyone been modifying the DB?

Comment: Firstly, thank you.  nothing data-based done. Can this be done externally? So is this attack with an outside query? I don't have much English, I hope I could tell

Comment: I do not think this is an attack - for some reason whatever is running the query is attempting to use one collation on data that is stored in another collation.  Not sure where it's coming from because the only info we have is the error code.

Comment: What can I do about this, please help. Provide a road map.